# How to programatically remove focus from an inline tinyMCE instance?

Tags: tinymce

When editing a div using the inline mode of tinyMCE, clicking outside of the editor will deactivate it (hide the toolbar, and basically return the div to "normal"). This is good.

There are some cases when the editor stays where it is even after losing focus:

- Hitting tab will make the editor lose focus (and bring focus to the address bar, for example), but the editor and toolbar stay there.
- Clicking on an element whose click event is captured by another script (like a Jquery-UI-Sortable element) will take focus away from the editor but keep the editor there.

In both cases, I have to click the body of the editor and then click out of it to get it to deactivate and disappear.

Is there a way to tell the inline editor instance to deactivate?

Comment: Seems like a legitimate TinyMCE bug.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't think I did but to be honest it was so long ago that I don't remember. The site that was for has since been rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I just have to answer for someone who might want to do the same thing.

[image: Inline Tintmce with focus on]

in other to remove focus, you can add this line of CSS to your global CSS file

```
.mce-edit-focus { outline: none !important; }
```

That's all, hope it helps!

[image: Result after added css]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a solution, you can find the solution here

[How do you clear the focus in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript/2520684)

```js
document.activeElement.blur()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can try below ways.

1. Remove class from tinymce editor.
   `$(editor.bodyElement).removeClass("mce-edit-focus")`
2. One can define dummy(no action) button in HTML page and call onclick of that button.

   `document.getElementById("noAction").click();`

Answer (score 0):

I solved something similar a while ago, this CSS entry helped me:

```
.tox .tox-edit-area::before {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```