# How can I remove :active from bootstrap button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website, where I have multiple buttons. Once a button is pressed I populate a list, though my problem is that the last pressed button keeps to be looking pressed (has the `:active` class). I thought about using angular's `$timeout` to reset the button, though the `removeClass` function doesn't do the trick.

My view looks like this:

```
    div(ng-controller='productButtonController')
    div(ng-repeat='product in products')
        div.col-md-4
            button.btn.btn-block.sell-button(id='{{product._id}}' ng-click='sell()'){{product.name}}
```

and my controller:

```
app.controller('productButtonController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'productServices', 'flash',
    function($scope, $timeout, productServices, flash) {
        productServices.getProducts()
            .success(function(result) {
                $scope.products = result.data
            })
            .error(showErrorMessage(flash))

        $scope.sell = function() {
            console.log(this.product)
            that = this
            $('#' + that.product._id).removeClass('active')
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: What does your code look like for the button? I was running into an issue where I was using bootstraps toggle to change the appearance and angulars style conditionals at the same time which was causing the button to be double toggled, so it didn't display correctly.

Comment: So show us your js/html code. If possible reproduce this fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to override the focus status of the bootstrap buttons you could do it with:

```
.btn:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Then your buttons should look like:

```
<button class="btn btn-default">My button 1</button>
```

It's also important that the stylesheet which overrides the button status is loaded **after** the bootstrap stylesheet.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, but the previous step only removes the outline. The background-color of the button still remains the same.

Since bootstrap doesn't append any active classes to the clicked element as far as i know you need to change the `:focus` status of the button:

```
$('#' + that.product._id).blur();
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 8):

1. Add the angular $window service to your dependencies for the
   controller
2. Call the blur method on the document's active element, which will be
   your button.

`$window.document.activeElement.blur();`

See [How do you clear the focus in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript]).

Answer (score 6):

This code from Justin Poehnelt's [handy GIST](https://gist.github.com/justinwp/5d29ecaa7a9b934defe6) solves this elegantly.

```
app.directive('blur', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                element.blur();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Add the blur attribute to a button/element you need blurred after click. Eg.

```
<button type="button" blur>Click me</button>
```

Comment: This works best, as you can then use it wherever needed in your app.

Comment: Good solution. Had to change to `element[0].blur();` to make it work.