# How to remove focus from button after closing javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with a bootstrap element on it.

```
<button title="delete" type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-sr"  data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash white"></span></button></a>';
```

It has a css property which I color it red.

When user clicks the delete button, a JavaScript confirmation will come out.

The problem is whenever i click cancel, the button will be focused. How do I remove the focused button?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', ':not(form)[data-confirm]', function(e) {
        if( !confirm($(this).data('confirm')) ) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: look at this:
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript

Comment: If you plan to support the blind and those needing ARAI tags, then you _should_ leave the focus where it was before opening the dialog. Otherwise it gets confusing for the user not knowing where the focus was put.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe could you try to **[`blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)** the button?

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', ':not(form)[data-confirm]', function(e) {
        if( !confirm($(this).data('confirm')) ) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).blur(); // to make the focus disappear
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: wew.. ty i feel like i really need to study more... btw thank you

Comment: No worries. Happy coding! _(feel free to accept the answer as the best suitable for you)_

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).blur();
```

over

```
document.activeElement.blur()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).blur();
```

removes the focus