# Javascript remove 'focus' event listener

Tags: javascript

I want to remove 'focus' event listener from element using plain javascript but not working

```
document.getElementById("txttaskdateDeploy").removeEventListener("focus", function(e){});
```

but below jquery works

```
$("#txttaskdateDeploy").unbind("focus");
```

can anyone tell why its not working in plain javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you clear the focus in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript)

Comment: You are creating a new function when you should pass an existing listener. `function(e){}` creates a new function which was not a listener before.

Comment: @ArnabRoy — No. The question is about removing the focus **event listener** not the focus itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the specific event listener that you want to remove to the `removeEventListener` method, instead of just passing an empty function.

An example of how this should be done would be:

```
const listener = function(e) {
  console.log('focused!'); // do anything here
} 

// Add event listener 
document.getElementById("txttaskdateDeploy").addEventListener("focus", listener);

// When you want to remove the event listener 
document.getElementById("txttaskdateDeploy").removeEventListener("focus", listener);
```

Answer (score 6):

The second argument you pass to `removeEventListener` has to be the function you want to remove.

You have a function expression there, so it will create a brand new function. Since it is a new function, it can't match any of the existing event listeners, so none of them will be removed.

This could work:

```
const x = function (e) { console.log(1); };
foo.addEventListener("focus", x);
foo.removeEventListener("focus", x);
```

But this won't (two different but identical functions are not the same function):

```
foo.addEventListener("focus", function (e) { console.log(1); });
foo.removeEventListener("focus", function (e) { console.log(1); });
```