# Remove focus from the span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tippyjs

I have below jsfiddle and I have tried few ways mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript) SO question but I am unable to remove the focus from "feedback" span after clicking on jquery confirm cancel button.

Steps:

1. Click on feedback
2. Click on cancel button on the popup
3. Feedback span again shows tippy js tip box.

I have tried jquery blur and document.activeElement.blur() but its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  tippy('#feedback', {
    placement: 'right',
    arrow: true,
    content: "Share your feedback."
  });
});

$('#feedback').click(function() {
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Feedback',
    useBootstrap: false,
    content: '' +
      '<form action="" class="formName">' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<input type="text" class="name form-control" required />' +
      '</div>' +
      '</form>',
    buttons: {
      formSubmit: {
        text: 'Send Feedback',
        btnClass: 'btn-blue',
        action: function() {

        }
      },
      cancel: function() {
        // $("#feedback").blur();
        // document.activeElement.blur();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/master/css/jquery-confirm.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/master/js/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
<span id="feedback" style="cursor:pointer;">
  feedback
</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sw8gpuoa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you. I unfocus when click event occurs and it seem work.

```
$('#feedback').click(function() {
    $(this).blur(); // unfocus when click event occur
    $.confirm({
                title: 'Feedback',
                useBootstrap: false,
                content: '' +
                    '<form action="" class="formName">' +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="name form-control" required />' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</form>',
                buttons: {
                    formSubmit: {
                        text: 'Send Feedback',
                        btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                        action: function () {

                        }
                    },
                    cancel: function () {
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: This is a rather hacky way of doing this, which is unnecessary when the `tippy` library includes a method to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the default triggers for `tippy` are `click` and `focus`. Hence when the modal is dismissed the tooltip is shown again when focus returns to the element.

To fix this set the `trigger` property to `'click mouseenter'`. The removal of `focus` will fix your issue. Adding `mouseenter` means that the tooltip will be shown on hover, but can be removed if you don't need that behaviour.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  tippy('#feedback', {
    trigger: 'click mouseenter', // add this property
    placement: 'right',
    arrow: true,
    content: "Share your feedback."
  });

  $('#feedback').click(function() {
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Feedback',
      useBootstrap: false,
      content: '<form action="" class="formName"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="name form-control" required /></div></form>',
      buttons: {
        formSubmit: {
          text: 'Send Feedback',
          btnClass: 'btn-blue',
          action: function() {
            // do something...
          }
        },
        cancel: function() {
          // do something...
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/master/css/jquery-confirm.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/master/js/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
<span id="feedback" style="cursor:pointer;">
  feedback
</span>
```

Also note that I placed all the jQuery logic in a single document.ready handler; you don't need multiple.

Comment: Thank you Rory. This works but this still puts an outline on the span on cancel button event.   $(this).blur();  before opening confirm popup works correct.

Comment: The outline comes from Bootstrap. If you don't want it you can remove it in CSS. I've updated the answer to show you how

Comment: Ah ok. I have use of bootstrap in my actual code. So, cannot remove it.

Comment: No, I'm not saying you need to remove Bootstrap, just add the style to the `#feedback` element as I did in my answer

Comment: Got it. Anyway thanks a lot for your help. Never knew there is a trigger property available in tippy

Comment: Glad to help, but note that the method in the other answer is a little hacky and may not work in all browsers.