# Reset focus when <h1> renders in react

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, focus, onfocus, autofocus

When a new page heading renders, I want to reset focus on that page, such that hitting `<tab>` will cause the browser to go to the focusable/tabbable element *after* this primary page heading.

Answer (score 0):

```
const PageTitle = ({title}) => {
  const titleHeaderRef = useRef(null as null | HTMLHeadingElement);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (titleHeaderRef.current !== null) {
      // First, make the element focus-able.
      titleHeaderRef.current.setAttribute('tabIndex', '-1');

      // Reset focus to this primary header.
      titleHeaderRef.current.focus();
      titleHeaderRef.current.blur();

      // Finally, make the element non-focus-able.
      titleHeaderRef.current.removeAttribute('tabIndex');

      // To see this behavior in action, wrap this dom calls in a 5 second setTimeout, and tab around the page before this timeout is hit.
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Typography ref={titleHeaderRef}>
      {title}
    </Typography>
  );
};
```

Comment: This SO page was helpful starting point:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript