# CKEditor 5 - how to remove focus (blur) programatically

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I'm using ck editor classic (version: 38.1.1) and have a scenario where I want to remove focus from a ck editor (when scrolling, the sticky header is on a strange position when the focused component leaves the screen and then move back), so I want to 'blur' the ck editor, so that once user enters it again, the sticky header is on correct position (I'm using the 'checkIfShouldBeSticky ' function).

According to the [focus documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/ui/focus-tracking.html), focusing on the editor is easily achievable with:

```
editor.editing.view.focus();
```

However, there is no 'blur' method on view. I've tried focusing on other html element, clicking on other elements, even calling the bellow methods with no success:

```
this.editor.editing.view.document.isFocused = false
this.editor.editing.focusTracker.remove();
this.editor.ui.focusTracker.remove();
```

The closes I got was using 'focusTracked.remove()' which did remove the 'focused' color from ckeditor, but if the user type it still insert the characters into the input.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but focusing on other html elements, e.g. a textbox, works fine. I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/codingstill/avfwre02/) to check. In my example, I am focusing on the editor after 1000ms, which it works. After 5000ms, I focus on a textbox, which also works. I mean after the 5000ms, when I type, I write on the textbox.

Comment: One thing I didnt mention is that the component (I'm using it on angular) that has the ckeditor has only this component, so there is nothing else I can focus there (dont know what else will be present on usage). I tried created a hidden input/button (using display-none), but it never focus on it. If I remove the displa-none it focus on the component, and ckeditor focus is lost.

Comment: Found a way that works https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551843/5669584 instead of requiesting to ckeditor / focusing on something else, I call blur on the active element. It removes the focus from the ckeditor and I do not need to create a hack input just for changing focus :)